# How to get location x,y on selection of each object in 2d diagram using Viewer api?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Using Viewer API, I displaying the 2d diagram. Is that possible to get the location x,y values on the selection of each value?

I am getting some properties of the object.  But it doesn't contain any properties related to X, Y of it? Is any way to get the position?

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Hi, it looks to me this property is missed when translating for some specific reason. I am checking with engineer team. In 3D model, you can get the position of the object by dumping its fragments mesh. However, in 2D drawing, some blocks or entities might share the same fragment, so it does not make sense to check its position.

Comment: Hi jothi pandiyan, sorry, I i did not get response from the engineer team. So I logged a change request to track it: LMV-2835 DWG attribute missing [block position]. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi Xiaodong Lang, Thanks for your reply. Actually, not only block position I am not able to get the positions(X, Y) of an ellipse, circle, polyline, Line (StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY, CenterX, CenterY).  I have edited above question to add ellipse properties. Check this once.